# how to manually create instance of Type T?

Tags: java

I have this

```
public interface ScreenObject<PK> extends ScreenRenderable {

    public PK getPrimaryKey();  
    public String getTypeName();
}
```

How do i create manual instance of this object? i tried

```
 ScreenObject<PK>  p2 = new ScreenObject<PK>("hello", "world");
```

But this doesn't work.
Do advice! thanks in advance.

Comment: `ScreenObject` is an interface. You cannot instantiate it. You'll either find a class that implements it or implement it yourself.

Comment: And `PK` is a type parameter - you need to specify the type argument you want. You'll also need a suitable contructor to call...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an object for the interface. For creating an object, you should provide an implementation class and implement all abstract methods.

From your question you should do something like this

```
public class ImplClass<PK> implements ScreenObject<PK> {

      // create a constructor with two String arguments

      public ImplClass(String obj1, String obj2) {
            //write your logic
      }

      // Do all the implementations for the abstract classes.
}
```

Then you can create the instance by

```
ScreenObject<Type Parameter> p2 = new ImplClass<> ("Hello", "World");
```

Please refer [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/interface-in-java) for understanding more about interfaces

Note: PK is a type parameter which makes you write generic codes. refer [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm) for more details